# Prevent browser from caching input control value

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

Most browsers will remember what you've typed into an input control so that you don't have to type it in again. Usually, this is useful

I have a field in which the user needs to enter a unique reference for a newly created resource.  The reference us unique and a user should never type the same in twice (this would return an error).

Is it possible to tell the browser *not* to cache the entries for this field only?  Auto-complete is causing user input errors in this case.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: @AdamAzad evactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @AdamAzad Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `input` attribute `autocomplete="off"` to prevent browsers from filling in forms.

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" />
```

Bear in mind, forms that are actually *submitted* will save the data to Autofill database in the browser. Forms submitted through AJAX will not result in saving inputs.